# Extract data frames within a list and print in pdf

Tags: r, loops, pdf-generation

I have a list of `n` data frames. Let's call the list `Y`.
It looks something like this:

```
$Profession1
Searchterm         Product            Quantity
internist          Der Internist      3
pneumo news        Pneumo News        1
der urologe        Der Urologe        5    


$Profession2
Searchterm         Product            Quantity
der nervenarzt     Der Internist      7
der kardiologe     Der Kardiologe     2
.piefel            Strahlentherapie   6
therapiedes zenker Pathophysiologie   1

.
.
.
.
.
.

$Profession(n)
Searchterm         Product            Quantity
tuberkolose        Tuberkolose        2
und notfallmedizin Notfall            3
rechtsmedizin      Rechtsmedizin      9
```

Now, I want to print each of the data frame on a new page in a pdf file. The number of records or rows in each data frame differs. I think I should loop first over every data frame and then loop it over every row in the data frame in the list, but I don't know how to.

Thanks.

Comment: are you comfortable using rmarkdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-RMarkdown solution:

Firstly, I have made a reproducible example list of tables using the `iris` dataset within R`

```
tables <- list(a =  iris[1:10,], b = iris[11:20,], c = iris[21:30,])
```

Using the `grid` and `gridExtra` packages, you can create tables as graphical devices. `lapply` is used to run `grid.table()` for each of the tables in the list, and all of this is wrapped in the function `pdf` which saves the output to a PDF:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

pdf(file = "name_of_file.pdf")
lapply(tables, function(x){
  grid.newpage()
  grid.table(x)})
dev.off()
```

This results in a multipage PDF file:

[image]

> **Further reading:** learn how you can style grid graphics here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html . You can change the colour of the tables, formatting etc.

Comment: I tried your solution which works perfectly, but unfortunately it doesn't work on my list, I think because the data set is quite large. The total number of rows (including all the data frames) is around 60,000.

Comment: Combine my answer with the approach explained in the other: mine gives you the structure to loop through multiple tables, the other shows how to split them. Unfortunately, I am not able to teach all the details of R

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution helped :)

Comment: I would like to extend my question further. Can you help me on how do I include the data frame's name (eg. Profession1, Profession2 as shown in my data frame) as a header in my pdf file one time each whenever a new data frame starts?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in R you don't need to iterate over the rows within a given table. Printing a table should print it's entire contents - some data-frame like structures (tibble, data.table) will print out just the top few lines unless you modify some arguments to print, but you certainly shouldn't need to iterate over the rows.

Here's how I do this in Rmarkdown.

Ensure you have a data-frame printing option chosen in your markdown header:

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%Y-%m-%d')`"
output:
    pdf_document:
        df_print: kable
---
```

Import these for use later

````
```{r}
library(purrr)
library(knitr)
```
````

Set up your data

````
```{r}
# set up my_tables
```
````

Make a text representation of a printed data-frame for each of the data-frames in your list

````
```{r}
out <- purrr::map_chr(
    my_tables,
    function(tt){
        knit_expand(text = "{{tt}}")
        }
    )
```
````

Print out the collection of data-frames

```
`r paste(knit(out), collapse = "\n")`
```

---

If you want to work inside R itself, you could call grid::grid.table multiple times to print your tables to a pdf:

```
library(grid)
pdf("my_file.pdf")
for(tt in my_tables){
  grid.table(tt)
  }
dev.off()
```

Comment: Hi Russ, Thank you so much for your help but I am just a baby when it comes to R. Hence have never used Rmarkdown. Is there a way to do in R?

Comment: Thank you Russ for the taking out the time to help me. :)

Comment: with some modifications, yes.

Comment: Cool. Could you post your working version of the code as an answer and `accept` it, please